# Invalid Bundle - Info.plist should specify CFBundleSupportedPlatforms with an array containing a single platform

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an archive to app store connect. Archive uploads successfully. When i go to app store connect and see it in activity section. It says "**This build is invalid**", with red exclamation mark. I checked my developer email and got this message

> `We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "App name". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Invalid Bundle - Info.plist should specify CFBundleSupportedPlatforms
>   with an array containing a single platform `

---

I searched for solution and found out that my info.plist should contain a key "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" with an array value having a single entry "iPhoneOS".

**Added the required key Values**

[image: Info.plist]

So i added the required key and value in info.plist. I made the archive again and submitted. But i am facing the same issue **AGAIN**. red exclamation mark appears in 'Activity' Section and when i click on this mark, it says This build is invalid

[image: app store connect]

I searched for a solution. I found answers involving nested bundles containing simulator platform. But these are not relevant in my case

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If you are using third party sdk's then check their plist as well

Comment: check for what ? I have around 40 libraries in my code. Should all info.plist contain the key `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms ` ?

Comment: Google Maps require this key. but I am not sure about other libraries. So you can try by adding this in info.plist of all libraries.

Comment: Just remove `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` item from Info.plist, and when building, Xcode will automatically add the key with value `iPhoneOS`, which is expected by Apple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Found the solution

Previous developer copy pasted some third party SDKs which included the value `iPhoneSimulator` for `key` CFBundleSupportedPlatforms in plist files

This was not visible in XCode(inside plist files of 3rd party SDK's). I had to go to my project directory (In Finder) and examine info.plist files of third part SDKs.

Two of the plistFiles in SDKs included value `iPhoneSimulator` along with `iPhoneOS`. This was causing the trouble.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: In case you don't know where this info.plist is,  just search in the whole project anything that matches `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms`, that was the way I fixed it.

Comment: Just remove `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` item from Info.plist, and when building, Xcode will automatically add the key with value `iPhoneOS`, which is expected by Apple.

Comment: @CristianMartinez incase if the question is still open, it is inside .framework file.

Answer (score 0):

the best case for me :
Go To Build Setting -> Architectures -> Supported Platforms.
Select Value iOS Make it Other and remove iphonesimulator from and make just iphoneos and if you have target Like (Content - Services) Notification make the same :
Go To Build Setting -> Architectures -> Supported Platforms.
Select Value iOS Make it Other and remove iphonesimulator from and make just iphoneos